# Ethereum Mist client crashing on startup

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have been using the Mist client as an Ethereum wallet recently.

It took a long time to download all the blocks and view my current balance but eventually it synced fully to the blockchain.

Now when I try and open the client it crashes on "Ethereum Node Starting Up".

Is there a way I can view error logs in the console?

**EDIT** this is the error I get - reinstalling did not solve the problem:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null
    at Socket.proc.stdout.on.data (/opt/Mist/resources/app.asar/modules/ethereumNode.js:428:46)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:560:20)
```

Comment: To check log files, go to your ethereum directory -> geth -> nodes, you'll see all the log files.

Comment: Where is the default save location?